# Why server showing blank white page after importing Material UI icons/module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Below is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Chat.css"
import { Avatar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SearchOutlined';
import AttachFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AttachFile';
import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';


function Chat() {
  return (
    <div className='chat'>
      <div className='chat__header'>
        <Avatar />

        <div className='chat__headerInfo'>
          <h3>Room name</h3>
          <p>Last seen at...</p>
        </div>
        <div className='chat__headerRight'>
          <IconButton>
            <SearchOutlinedIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <AttachFileIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chat
```

In above text according to everything I have done is correct inspite of that server page is getting white blank

I tried to import Material UI icons as soon as I import it server is showing blank page please solve this problem

Comment: Is anything rendered on the page, can you see anything in the developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the import statement as:

```
import { Avatar, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
```

@material-ui/core is no longer being developed I think. If you've installed the MUI packages as provided in their documentation, this ought to work.